# Get unique users in a given time period in Mixpanel

Tags: android, mixpanel, jql

How do I get the unique users who have installed and launched the app at least once through JQL in Mixpanel? I am using the below mentioned query, however, the number of users thus determined does not tally up with the number on playstore. The count thus obtained is almost thrice the number of install numbers provided in Playstore.

```
function main() {
  return Events({
    from_date: "2017-03-19",
    to_date: "2017-06-21"  })
  .groupBy(
     ["distinct_id"],
     mixpanel.reducer.null()
  )
.reduce(mixpanel.reducer.count());
}
```

In this query, I am assuming that distinct ids are created only after the first launch of the app and are unique for every user. However, this does not seem to be correct. Kindly help

Answer (score 1):

> mixpanel.reducer.null() - Always return null. See [api](https://mixpanel.com/help/reference/jql/api-reference).

This query returning unique users with current events.

```
function main() {
  return Events({
    from_date: "2017-03-19",
    to_date: "2017-06-21",
    event_selectors: [
        { event: 'App Install' },
        { event: 'App Opened' }
    ]    
  })
  .groupByUser(mixpanel.reducer.any())
  .reduce(mixpanel.reducer.count());
}
```

Chaining `groupByUser` transformation results in a collection of objects with the following structure: `{ [distinct_id], value: any }`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the count does not match because you are not filtering the events you want to count, if you only want to count the number of App Installs and App Opens then you must specify this in the query. The way to do this is to add the function `event_selectors` in your query.

```
function main() {
  return Events({
    from_date: "2017-03-19",
    to_date: "2017-06-21",
    event_selectors: [
        {event: 'App Install'},
        {event: 'App Opened'}
    ]    
  })
  .groupBy(
     ["distinct_id"],
     mixpanel.reducer.null()
  )
.reduce(mixpanel.reducer.count());
}
```

I'm not sure if `App Install` and `App Opened` are the appropriate names for the events you want to count.

Hope this helps you out!